# Rendering Form Panel inside Extjs Grid Row Expander's rowBodyTpl

Tags: extjs5

Form Panel not rendered properly in Extjs grid rowexpander's rowbodytpl.Trying to render form panel but it is not properly rendered.Labels and textfields are rendered properly but when they are used inside form panel they do not display.

```
plugins:[
              {
                ptype:'rowexpander',
                  rowBodyTpl:[
                     '<div class="row-expander-ct" id="row-expander-ct"></div>'
                 ]
                 }
              ]

        grid.store.on({
            delay:1,
            load:function() {
                Ext.each(grid.el.query('.row-expander-ct'), function(ct) {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
                        title:'Form Panel',
                        //width:'100%',
                        //height:'100%',
                                      cls:'testform',
                                      bodyPadding:10,
                              //initComponent:function(){
                                  //var te=this;
                                  //Ext.applyIf(this,{

                                      items:[

                                          {
                                              xtype:'textfield',
                                              fieldLabel:'Item',
                                              name:'Item',
                                              allowBlank:false,
                                              itemId:'txtItem'
                                          },
                                          {
                                              xtype:'textfield',
                                              fieldLabel:'Unit Cost',
                                              name:'UnitCost',
                                              allowBlank:false,
                                              itemId:'txtUnitCost'
                                          },
                                          {
                                              xtype:'textfield',
                                              fieldLabel:'Margins',
                                              name:'Margins',
                                              allowBlank:false,
                                              itemId:'txtMargins'
                                          },
                                          {
                                              xtype:'textfield',
                                              fieldLabel:'Unit Price',
                                              name:'UnitPrice',
                                              allowBlank:false,
                                              itemId:'txtUnitPrice'
                                          },
                                          {
                                              xtype:'textfield',
                                              fieldLabel:'Quantity',
                                              name:'Quantity',
                                              allowBlank:false,
                                              itemId:'txtQuantity'
                                          },
                                          {
                                              xtype:'textfield',
                                              fieldLabel:'Retail Price',
                                              name:'RetailPrice',
                                              allowBlank:false,
                                              itemId:'txtRetailPrice'
                                          },
                                        {
                                            xtype:'button',
                                            text:'Add',
                                      id:'btnadd',
                                            scope:this,
                                      listeners:{
                                          click:function(button,e){
                                              alert('hi');
                                          }
                                      }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype:'button',
                                            text:'Reset'
                                        }

                                      ],
                        renderTo:ct
        //                
                    });
                });
         }
        });
        grid.store.load();
```

Comment: grid.store.on method is written inside grid's viewready event

Answer (score 1):

```
    viewready:function(grid){
                        grid.view.on('expandBody',function(rowNode, record, expandRow, eOpts){
                            //console.log(record);
                            var store=grid.store;
                                var count=store.getCount();
                            if(record.get('Id')!="-" && record.get('Id')!=count){
                                displayInnerContent(record.get('Id'),record);
                            }
                            else{
                                //var store=grid.store;
                                //var count=store.getCount();
                                var emptyRecId=store.last();
                            console.log(record);
                               displayInnerEmptyContent(count); 
                            }

                        });

                        grid.view.on('collapsebody', function (rowNode, record, expandRow, eOpts) {
                            destroyInnerContent(record);
                        });
                    }
function displayInnerContent(renderId,rec){
            //console.log(rec.get('Item'));
            var innerForm=Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
                title:'Form Panel',
                              cls:'testform',
                              bodyPadding:10,
            renderTo:'row-'+renderId,
                      //initComponent:function(){
                         // var te=this;
                        //  Ext.applyIf(this,{

                              items:[

                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      fieldLabel:'Item',
                                      name:'Item',
                                      allowBlank:false,
                                      itemId:'txtItem',
                                      value:rec.get('Item')
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      fieldLabel:'Unit Cost',
                                      name:'UnitCost',
                                      allowBlank:false,
                                      itemId:'txtUnitCost',
                                      value:rec.get('UnitCost')
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      fieldLabel:'Margins',
                                      name:'Margins',
                                      allowBlank:false,
                                      itemId:'txtMargins',
                                      value:rec.get('Margins')
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      fieldLabel:'Unit Price',
                                      name:'UnitPrice',
                                      allowBlank:false,
                                      itemId:'txtUnitPrice',
                                      value:rec.get('UnitPrice')
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      fieldLabel:'Quantity',
                                      name:'Quantity',
                                      allowBlank:false,
                                      itemId:'txtQuantity',
                                      value:rec.get('Quantity')
                                  },
                                  {
                                      xtype:'textfield',
                                      fieldLabel:'Retail Price',
                                      name:'RetailPrice',
                                      allowBlank:false,
                                      itemId:'txtRetailPrice',
                                      value:rec.get('RetailPrice')
                                  },
                                {
                                    xtype:'button',
                                    text:'Add',
                              itemId:'btnadd',
                                    //scope:this,
                              listeners:{
                                  afterrender:function(button){
                                    button.getEl().set({
                                    "data-id": renderId
                                });  
                                  },
                                  click:function(button,e){
                                      var form=Ext.query('.testform');
                                      var store=Ext.getStore('TreeGridStore');
                                      console.log(button.el.dom.dataset.id);
                                      var item=store.findRecord('Id',button.el.dom.dataset.id);
                                  }
                              }
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype:'button',
                                    itemId:'btnreset',
                                    text:'Reset'
                                }

                              ] 
                        //  });

                          //this.callParent(arguments);
                     // } 
            });

            innerForm.getEl().swallowEvent([
                'mousedown', 'mouseup', 'click',
                'contextmenu', 'mouseover', 'mouseout',
                'dblclick', 'mousemove'
            ]);
        }
function destroyInnerContent(record) {

    var parent = document.getElementById('row-'+record.get('Id'));
    var child = parent.firstChild;

    while (child) {
        child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }

}
```

Here create form panel in displayInnerContent and destroy it in destroyInnerContent methods.And call the methods in grid's viewready event on grid's expandbody and collapse body events.